# directive link function not running but template, controller, does

Tags: angularjs

I am having a weird issue with my directive. My understanding is that the `link` function should run immediately as a constructor would. The strange thing is that my directive is working in every other aspect except the `link` function. My `controller` function is working, and the `template` is correctly replacing my custom element tag on  the DOM.

*View*

```
<div id="testApp" ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
 <sb-tokenized-filter on-search="onSearch();" search-query="searchQuery">
 </sb-tokenized-filter>
</div>
```

On my view I also have a test app and test controller within a script tag as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('testApp', ['tokenizedFilter']).controller('testController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.tokens = [];
        $scope.searchQuery = null;

        $scope.onSearch = function () {
            console.log("search selected", $scope.searchQuery, $scope.tokens);
        }
    }]);


    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        var bootstrapTarget = document.getElementById('testApp');
        angular.bootstrap(angular.element(bootstrapTarget), ['testApp']);
    });
})();
</script>
```

*Here is a trimmed down version of my directive*

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular.module('tokenizedFilter', ['ui.bootstrap']).directive('sbTokenizedFilter', function($sce, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {

            onSearch: '&onSearch',
            tokens: '=',
            searchQuery: '=searchQuery',
        },
        template: '<div class="row">...', //works, replaces the DOM element with what I have in here
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            //stuff happening here
            //this works as well
        },
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            //this never outputs to the console :(
            //not working...
            console.log('in link');
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            //this is hit and does output stuff to the console.
        }
    }
});
})();
```

I'm sure it's some small detail that I'm missing here.. I've been on pluralsight watching their directive videos and have also read angular's docs but I do not see what I am doing wrong here.

**Why does every functionality of my directive seem to work except the link function?**

Comment: Because you defined compile function. Link is ignored in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [the doc](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-compile-):

> **link**
>
> This property is used only if the `compile` property is not defined.

What you actually should do is make your `compile` function return a value:

> Returning a (post-link) function is equivalent to registering the
>   linking function via the `link` property of the config object when the
>   `compile` function is empty.
>
> Returning an object with function(s) registered via `pre` and `post`
>   properties allows you to control when a linking function should be
>   called during the linking phase.

Comment: ah crap. that would do it.

Comment: One quick question if you have the time. How would I access the directive's element to recompile it with `$compile` if I can't specify a `link` function? The `compile` function does not have access to the scope. The only thought to mind is hacking it with an id attribute and using js `document.getElementById` to accomplish this

Comment: nevermind, I see the `controller` function can take an injected `$element` param

Comment: It's hard to say without example given, but in general you should avoid recompilation. If you need your template to be chosen depending on params (there should be better ways to do this, btw), you can always use a `template` function.